# Google+ javascript/php login api

Tags: javascript, php, google-plus, google-signin

Can you help me please how to login by G+ Javascript and PHP?
Javascript works fine, but when I want to verify the token on server it throws an exceptions. I go according this page:https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth but there is only Java/Python.
Javscript code:

```
function onSignIn(googleUser)
{
    var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token,
        profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();

    console.log(id_token);

    $.ajax({
        url : "{link :Signgoogle:in}",
        accepts : 'json',
        type : 'post',
        data : {
            'token' : id_token
        },
...
```

PHP code:

```
public function actionIn()
{
    $token = $_POST['token'];

    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setScopes('email');
    $client->setApplicationName(self::APP_NAME);
    $client->setDeveloperKey(self::SERVER_KEY);

    $client->setAccessToken($token); // This throws an exception

    $data = $client->verifyIdToken($token)->getAttributes();
...
```

`$client->setAccessToken` throws an exception: `Could not json decode the token`. Can you tell me how to verify the user login? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: Now I change id_token in Javascript to: `var jsResult = JSON.stringify(googleUser.getAuthResponse())` and send it to PHP but $client->setAccessToken($jsResponse) throws Invalid token format exception. Format look like setAccessToken() requires.

Comment: Ofcourse $client->setAccessToken() throws an exception cause it expects access_token but I have only id_token from js API. So it looks I should use $client->verifyIdToken() only. But it kills me an Apache. Somethig is wrong and I dont know what.

Comment: Ok so I found another flow which you can find here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31215646/google-login-via-javascript-and-php

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same problem and I found out the following solution for your problem:

```
auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
        function(googleUser) {
            var link = server+"user/google-plus-login"
            console.log(link)
            console.log(googleUser)
            var Name = googleUser['wc']['Ld']
            var mail = googleUser['wc']['wc']
            var image = googleUser['wc']['zt']
            var access_token = googleUser['Ka']['access_token']
        }, function(error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
        });
```

Hopefully this works for you as well!

Answer (score 0):

For getting the client details you just pass the token to this api https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token= < your_token >

```
if (isset ( $_REQUEST['token'] ) && $_REQUEST['token'] != '') {

    $response = file_get_contents ( 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=' . $_REQUEST['token'] );

    $response = json_decode ( $response );

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r ( $response );
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

fount an example here : http://wiki.workassis.com/implementing-google-sign-in-for-websites

Answer (score 0):

Hey reason is from ajax you are passing `id_token` and in php, you are verifying `access_token` in `setAccessToken($token)`.
So to verify and set access_token you have to send `access_token` as well as follows:

```
function onSignIn(googleUser)
{
    var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token,
    var access_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse(true).access_token,
        profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();

    console.log(id_token);

    $.ajax({
        url : "{link :Signgoogle:in}",
        accepts : 'json',
        type : 'post',
        data : {
            'token' : id_token,
            'access_token' : access_token
        },
```

and in backend check like this

```
public function actionIn()
{
    $token = $_POST['token'];
    $access_token = $_POST['access_token'];

    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setScopes('email');
    $client->setApplicationName(self::APP_NAME);
    $client->setDeveloperKey(self::SERVER_KEY);

    $client->setAccessToken($access_token); // This will not throw exception

    $data = $client->verifyIdToken($token)->getAttributes();
...
```